# File css with 0kb in gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

My gulp save the css width 0kb.

This is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/v6y0qkux/

```js
gulp.task('jpg', function () {
    gulp.src('./template/img/**/*.*')
            .pipe(changed('./dist/img/'))
            .pipe(imagemin({
                progressive: true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/img/'));
});
```

Sometimes it save as normal, but the most times, it save 0km.

Comment: What are you trying to do? And what is the expected outcome?

Comment: As we can see you aren't processing css minification. Explain what are you doing and you want to do with ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that comes from a project of mine.

You need to install the npm package : gulp-minify-css

```
npm install gulp-minify-css
```

Here is the code to handle minimification.

```
var minimifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('minify-css', function() {

return gulp.src([__dirname + '/your directory/*/**.css'])
    .pipe(minifyCss({comments:true, spare:true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + '/your directory destination'))
});
```